# Grab all text between nested matching characters recursively

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

This is an example input string:

`((#1662# - #[Réz-de-chaussée][Thermostate][Temperature Actuel]#) > 4) && #1304# == 1 and #[Aucun][Template][ReviseConfort#templateSuffix#]#`

and these are the required output strings:

```
#1662#
#[Réz-de-chaussée][Thermostate][Temperature Actuel]#
#1304#
#[Aucun][Template][ReviseConfort#templateSuffix#]#
```

I tried this regex, but it doesn't work:

```
~("|\').*?\1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\#(?:[^##]|(?R))*\#~
```

Comment: I'm sorry my exemple on the first edit containt a error. The delimiter caracte before and after is #.

Comment: I am afraid your question is unclear because there is a noticeable difference between what your pattern attempts to match and the sample input.  Please improve your question by providing a more realistic sample input -- or better -- sample input**s** that better represent the types of strings you will encounter.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all( '/\#((\d{1,4})|(\[[^0-9]+\]))[\#$]/'
              , '((#1662# - #[Réz-de-chaussée][Thermostate][Temperature Actuel]$) > 4) && #1304$ == 1 and #[Aucun][Template][ReviseConfort#templateSuffix#]#'
              , $matches
              );
foreach($matches[0] as $match)
    echo $match.PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one [`(?:#[^#[]+#|##(?:.+?]#){2}|#(?:.+?]#){1})`](https://regex101.com/r/WWabkj/2)

Explanation:

```
(?:
// Grabs everything between 1 opening # and 1 closing # tag that`s not #[ chars
   #[^#[]+#|
// Grabs everything between 2 opening # and 2 closing ]# tags
   ##(?:.+?]#){2}|
// Grabs everything between 1 opening # and 1 closing ]# tag
   #(?:.+?]#){1}
)
```

Comment: It's work fine but not for this ##foreach[name]#[Off]# the return is ##foreach[name]# and not ##foreach[name]#[Off]#

Comment: adapted to new situation, check now

Answer (score 0):

This situation is not particularly suited for recursion. It would be better to use a normal regex.

It's hard to tell for certain if the following will work for all other possible inputs, as you've only supplied two limited examples.

At least in those examples, the required closing `#`'s are followed either by a `)`, a space, or the end  of the line. Using a negative look-ahead for these values allows us to capture the internally nested `#`'s:

```
#(?:[^#]|#(?![\s)]|$))+#
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XUh6ol/1)